# How is the O'Brien-Fleming constant calculated and how does the procedure control error rates?

Tags: clinical-trials, sequential-analysis

O'Brien-Fleming is a commonly used interim analysis procedure in clinical trials. The procedure is used when $N$ tests are performed in sequence. For each test $n \in \{1, ..., N\}$, a test statistic $S_n$ is calculated and the null hypothesis $H_0$ is rejected if $\mid S_n \mid \geq c_{OBF} \sqrt{\frac{N}{n}}$. The constant $c_{OBF}$ is chosen such that the Type 1 error rate of the procedure is a pre-specified  $\alpha$.

O'Brien and Fleming seem to derive the constant for a $\chi^2$ test, but their notation differs from that seen in textbooks and I can't follow the derivation. There are several software packages for calculating the constant, like `ldBounds::` and `gsDesign::` in R. A lot of discussion about the test makes reference to tables of constants or offers very little information about how the constant is chosen. This makes me think that the calculation is either a) extremely obvious or b) extremely difficult. At any rate, I'd like to understand the test so I can use it and the biggest hurdle seems to be understanding how the constant is calculated.

My question is: How is the OBF constant calculated, and how does the procedure control the error rate of an experiment?

Comment: Is “c” a constant, or could it be the hazard coefficient?

Comment: Demets and Lan [link](https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.4780131308) say $c_{OBF}$ is "calculated using the recursive density function and iterative interpolation such that
the desired type I error rate or alpha level is achieved under [H0]."  O'Brien and Fleming say that it is the maximum of $\{[W(n/N)]^2\}$ where $\{W(t)|0\let\le1\}$ "represents Brownian motion".  Although I understand that W(t) represents a Wiener process, I don't follow their explanation and may post my own related question.